# Jquery Datatable Checkbox checked count Error

Tags: jquery, checkbox, datatables

Am Using the datatable to list items in my web page.All the rows are associated with a check box .The number of checkboxes checked are getting right in single page. if i check a single checkbox in first page ,it alert a count 1, if a moved to 2nd page using pagination links  and check a checkbox there..stil it shows a count of 1. Why it is not considering the checked column in first page.
How can i get count 2 in this scenrio?

Comment: how about using `datatables select row` from http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/select_row.html

Comment: @Dhiraj Bodicherla .i hve used datatables select row but its not working in ie8 ,working in ie9 and other browsers?